# How to call to function with parameter from event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code which is working:

```
yauzl.open(filePath, function (err, zipFile) {
    zipFile.on('entry', (entry) =>{
        //console.log(entry.fileName);
        if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
            return;
        }
        zipFile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.info(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
    ...
```

Now I want to change the code a bit to make it more readable by doing something like the following:

```
yauzl.open(filePath, (err, zipFile) => {
    //zipFile = zipFile;
    if (err) {
        __rejectAndLog(err);
        return;
    }

    zipFile.on('entry', __processEntry(zipFile))
        .once('error', __rejectAndLog)
        .once('close', () => {
            console.log(`Unpacked ${numOfFiles} files`);
            resolve();
        });
    });
```

This is the processEntry:

```
function __processEntry(zipFile) {

    zipFile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
        if (err) {
            __rejectAndLog(err);
            return;
        }

        if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
            // directory file names end with '/'   
            return;
        }
```

Here I got the error `cannot use **openReadStream** of undefined`. How can I handle it?

```
zipFile.openReadStream(entry, (err, readStream) => {
```

In addition I need to pass also the entry `value` any idea?

Comment: use `zipFile.on('entry', __processEntry.bind(null, zipFile))`
`

Comment: @SaadShahd - Thanks do you know how should I pass the entry value also?

Comment: pass it to what from where?

Comment: like its in zipFile.on('entry', (entry) =>{  to pass it to function __processEntry I need to use it there...

Comment: it will be the second argument. so you should declare `function __processEntry(zipFile, entry) {`

Comment: but in the bind I dont need to add it somehow ?

Comment: What `bind` do is producing a new function bounded to the passed parameters. so `__processEntry.bind(null, zipFile)` produces `__processEntry` with the bounded first parameter equals zipFile.

Comment: @SaadShahd - so how does the entry is passed to the _processEntry function ?

Comment: No you don't, the listener `zipFile.on('entry', ` takes your bounded function and call it with arguments which in this case is `entry`

Comment: @SaadShahd - when I try what you suggested I got error :TypeError: zipFile.openReadStream is not a function ,any idea why?

Comment: What is the order of your arguments in the __processEntry declaration?

Comment: @SaadShahd - sorrry my mistake please put it as answer and I close it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bind `zipFile.on('entry', __processEntry.bind(null, zipFile))` and re-declare your __processEntry as `function __processEntry(zipFile, entry)`